# robot does not spawn in ros2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, roslaunch, urdf, spawn-model

I am trying to spawn custom urdf in ros2. I have following launch file

```py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    # urdf_file_name = 'urdf/AMR.urdf'  # Relative path from the package
    urdf_file_name = 'urdf/AMR.urdf'  # Relative path from the package


    # print("urdf_file_name : {}".format(urdf_file_name))

    urdf = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('amr_robot'),
        urdf_file_name)

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
            output='screen'),

        Node(
            package='gazebo_ros',
            executable='spawn_entity.py',
            name='urdf_spawner',
            output='screen',
            arguments=[
                "-topic", "/robot_description",
                "-entity", "AMR",
                "-robot_namespace", "/"  # Optional, set if necessary
            ]
        )
    ])
```

when I launch it only gazebo open and robot does not spawn

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The robot can not be instantiated because there is no `robot_description`

Comment: can you kindly fix it and give the correct launch file in answer section. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `robot_state_publisher` node is missing in the launch file. The `spawn_entity.py` node is waiting for a `urdf` string in the topic `robot_description`. But since `robot_state_publisher` is not included, there is no node publishing to that topic. Refer to this [link](https://github.com/blackcoffeerobotics/bcr_bot/blob/ros2/launch/gazebo.launch.py) for syntax/examples.